# AWS: I can't link my route 53 configuration to my S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have 2 route53 hosted zone, let's call them myfirsturl.com and mysecondurl.com. 
For both of them, I have created a bucket in S3 named after my domain names. I have verified it multiple times letter by letter. 
Both of my buckets have static content, available from the S3 endpoint, with the fine policy etc: the 2 endpoints work perfectly.

The 1st hosted zone has been bought in route53 and when I connect to it, it opens my static website, all is good. 
My second domain name has been transferred to Amazon last month, and in route 53 I can find the S3 bucket in the list of targets when I create the recordset, but it doesn't reach the static website

Another point: I have created a WP site a few days ago, behind a load balancer etc, and I linked wp.myfirsturl.com to it: it worked perfectly 
I tried the same with wp.mysecondurl.com, to the same load balancer, it never worked.

I can't find any idea has I can't see any difference between my 2 domain name, except where I bought it.

Another difference:
The 1st is something like `sometexte.info`
The 2nd is something like `sometext-othertext.fr`

Maybe the hyphen is a problem? (it's not, pertaining to the doc)

Someone has a lead, please?

Comment: So, unrelated to S3, it sounds like you have a hosted zone that isn't working.  If you can mention the domain name, it's pretty straightforward to troubleshoot this with tools like `dig` and `whois` but without knowing the domain, it's a little tricky knowing exactly where to start.

Comment: I think you're right, my problem seems to be on the hosted zone. the domain name is `cherrier-coste.fr`. It looks well configured for me, my NS are :
ns-1731.awsdns-24.co.uk.
ns-669.awsdns-19.net.
ns-283.awsdns-35.com.
ns-1366.awsdns-42.org.
I tried to use the NS of my other domain name, but it didn't change anything., idem with the SOA. I thought of a problem of TTL maybe, but it's been a month since I migrated my domain name to amazon, it's far more than the usual 2days TTL in DNS, no ?

Comment: Did you give up on this?

Answer (score 1):

The bucket must have the same name as your domain or subdomain in Route53. For example, if you want to use the subdomain acme.example.com, the name of the bucket must be acme.example.com. Have a look at [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html) documentation for more information.

Comment: Nice idea, but I thought about it already :( my buckets are well named `myfirsturl.com` and `mysecondurl.com` and I can see them in route53, which shows I made no typo (and I checked it multiple times)